# Can't Delete Document in Domino Xpage Application

Tags: lotus-domino, xpages

I have few simple Xpages, where i test and learn the newest features in Domino 8.5.3.
Now, after some latest changes somehow i'm not able to delete Documents. The Application asks me for the User Name and password, which i enter and which are correct. However, nothing happens (well, the system thinks few seconds over) and i'm asked for my credentials again... and again.. If i press "cancel" -> i got the expected result -> error 401.
The strange thing as well, if even i give for the "anonymous" the editor rights with the "delete documents" checked, i'm still asked for the credentials...

Well, i think I need now some ideas and tips where can i look after in order to solve the "undeletable documents" problem.

The "Delete" button is made using the Simple Action "Delete Selected Documents".

**Update:** After looking into the logs (thanks Simon O'Doherty for the hint below!) i found out the following message

`28.02.12 19:20: Exception Thrown
com.ibm.xsp.acl.NoAccessSignal: NotesException: Notes error: Document locking is enabled. You must lock the document before deleting.`

After removing the setting "Allow Document locking" everything works fine.
**The next question**, however, and it seems to be intresting, if i want to use this setting - how to make the standart actions (it looks like at least "Delete Selected Documents" has some problems) work properly ?
Or do i have to use SSJS only ?

Comment: Do you use Authors fields to protect the document? This might explain why you cannot delete. Are you connecting to a backend database that you and Anonymous do not have access to? This might explain the promprt for authentication.

Comment: no authors or readers fields are used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the ACL settings. Click Advanced tab. Check that "Maximum Internet name and password access" is at least a level that allows you to edit documents.

May need to restart your browser for that to be registered.

If it is still an issue at that point then the following Debug may give more hints.

1. Check the XPages logs in the IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT folder of the server.
2. Check the elements on the page are not being pulled from another location that would require access.
3. Check for Authors/Readers fields.
4. The following debug on the server will allow you to see when an ACL call is made, what is asked for and what it got.

**Warning** This is very verbose debug, so it should only be activated for the test. Also do not paste the results anywhere externally without first sanitizing. (as it would be confidential to you).

> DEBUG_THREADID=1
>
> DEBUG_SERVER_ACL=2

Comment: the problem is now solved. i looked upon the XPages logs in IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT folder and there it was ! 28.02.12 19:20: Exception Thrown
com.ibm.xsp.acl.NoAccessSignal: NotesException: Notes error: Document locking is enabled. You must lock the document before deleting.

Comment: Simon, where can i look up the results of DEBUG_SERVER_ACL=2 ?  I don't see any new files in the folder IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT....

Comment: It won't create new files. Instead it added extra information to the console.log files / domino console.  Good to hear it is now working :)

Answer (score 1):

I have also seen this behaviour in our application. 
The issue is caused by the "Allow document locking" option.
Either you do not need this feature; then just uncheck in the application properties. If you intend to use the feature, you have to lock the document in your code prior to deleting it.

Answer (score 1):

Add a execute script simple action before delete simple action and write the following code

```
var doc:NotesDocument = currentDocument.getDocument();
doc.lock();
```

or

```
dataSource.getDocument().lock();
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be as easy as:
- check your ACL. Do you have delete rights? Default is off

Comment: Then the maximum Internet access would be my next bet :-)

Comment: jeah, also checked, was Ok. in the meantime the problem is found, it was "Allow document locking" setting.